# I would like to create (duplicate) records depend on an interval dates

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, date

I have a problem about PL/SQL, I'm not expert in SQL and I would like to create records if I have two dates (start and end). I can do it with a table calendar but it's very slow (join). I think if I develop a loop could be better.

I show you an example:

Original table:
[image]

and I would like to get:
[image]

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
create table ORIGINAL_TABLE (contact, start_date, final_date, days, amount) as 
select 55555, to_Date('01012020', 'ddmmyyyy'), to_date('05012020', 'ddmmyyyy'), 5, 500 from dual union all
select 66666, to_Date('01102020', 'ddmmyyyy'), to_date('08102020', 'ddmmyyyy'), 8, 1000 from dual
;

with generate_rows as (
select level lvl
from dual connect by level <= (select max(DAYS) from original_table)
)
select contact, start_date, final_date, days, amount, ot.start_date + gr.lvl - 1 day
from ORIGINAL_TABLE ot, generate_rows gr
where ot.start_date + gr.lvl - 1 <= final_date
order by contact, start_date, day
;
```

Answer (score 0):

repetition of information is usually a sign of bad db design. Your problem is that you have got a many to many problem (a "day"(second table) can have many contracts and a "contract"(both) can have many days).
I have two recommendations since I am not sure what your intent for this database is:

1. if the days of a contract will always be between the starting date and the end date, you can simply not have a column for day (second table, last column), assuming that you or your program could count the days from the starting date (using the "days" column or simply the days between "start date" and "final date")
2. if the "day"(second table, last column) may not be all days from the start to end date, or may be different in any other way, you could have table one the way it is, and table two have just two columns (contract & day), since the contract will be a unique identifier that matches with all the other data (first date, last date, days etc). If the contract is not unique, and might be repeated, I would highly suggest creating some method of identification (id) for the contracts, since you will be able to store data much more consciously without unescesarry repetitions.

Answer (score 0):

please try this one:

Create sample data:

```
create table contact(contact, start_date, finish_date, days, amount)
as
select 55555, to_Date('01012020', 'ddmmyyyy'), to_date('05012020', 'ddmmyyyy'), 5, 500 from dual union all
select 66666, to_Date('01102020', 'ddmmyyyy'), to_date('08102020', 'ddmmyyyy'), 8, 1000 from dual union all
select 66666, to_Date('01112020', 'ddmmyyyy'), to_date('10112020', 'ddmmyyyy'), 10, 1500 from dual union all
select 55555, to_Date('04122020', 'ddmmyyyy'), to_date('10122020', 'ddmmyyyy'), 6, 2500 from dual;
```

Select statement:

```
select contact, start_Date, finish_date, days,amount, start_date + level - 1 as day
from contact
connect by  prior contact = contact and prior start_date = start_date and prior finish_date = finish_date and level <= days and prior sys_guid() is not null
order by contact, start_date, start_date + level -1;
```

Condition `level <= days` can be replaced with `level <= finish_date - start_date + 1` . It is up to you to decide.

Thanks.